# How to make a chat texteditor in html capable of displaying png smiley?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, contenteditable

I'm tryng to figure out a way to create a texteditor for a webpage capable of displaying png images (smileys) and get the text typed and the smileys(probably ids or something like that) using pure javascript.

I came across "contenteditable", where i can use a div, but i can figure out how to retrieve what's been typed in javascript.

Any suggestions? I'm not willing to use jquery, i'm only using pure js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img>` tag inside a `contenteditable` element and you can use [HTML input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) to capture the changes

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">See: <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/nO2hl.png"/> <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/iUDpH.png"/> all your text goes here with img<img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png"/></div>
```

style you contenteditable div:

```
[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
   max-height: 1.5em;
  max-width: 1.5em;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rpdheeya/

Comment: I now see how i can get at least a list of images inserted, but what about the text? and  how to know about the position of the images in the text?

Comment: you can type in the text in div , remove it, and to add png smileys you need to have a button next to div which will populate a list of smileys and when a user click on it then it is inserted in a div as <img> tag. If you want to get position on images inserted then you have to provide a unique id to inserted <img> and track it using that